# Difficulty differentiating the group expansions from elliptical from using systemic functional grammar

Tags: systemic-functional, ellipsis

An enthusiast of grammar, specifically Systemic Functional Grammar introduced Halliday.
Befuddled about differentiating the difference between an elliptical clause and expansion to phrase/groups.
Based on the definition itself, as long as only one element is involved, albeit the nominal group to nominal group, the adverbial group to prepositional phrase, it could be analyzed at the phrase rank, otherwise a clause poised with ellipsis.
However, I find some cases paradoxical to the definition in and of itself, as below:
[image: Nominal group expansion at the end, lethal, with a manner adjunct-“by degrees.”]

Is there anything I’m missing that exclude the case above from being analyzed as an elliptical clause?

Same seen in, where the even is another modal adjunct, an extra element together with the expansion of adverbial group.
[image]